# PopUp in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, popup

I want to use popUp element in windows phone (C#) to view a message on screen

I did the following:

```
popUpBanner = new Popup();
popUpBanner.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
popUpBanner.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
```

But the popup element appears in the top left of the screen .. not at the center

How can I solve this

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone the Pop up is not a UserControl class. Instead of centering the popup you want to center the ui elements within the popup's child element...

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, I updated my code and hope it helps you.
First lets get the screen size(i.e. Width & Height)

```
var width = System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
var height = System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
```

Lets create a StackPanel, adding background color to it and re-sizing the StackPanel according to the device screen resolution.

```
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
stackPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
stackPanel.Height = height / 4;
stackPanel.Width = width / 2;
```

Finally Create a Popup and add it as a children to the StackPanel.

```
Popup Popup1 = new Popup();
stackPanel.Children.Add(Popup1);
ContentPanel.Children.Add(stackPanel);
Popup1.IsOpen = true;
```

You are done. Modify your StackPanel size according to your need, since you got the screen resolution here.

Comment: The question is about centering, not setting offset which will not be sufficient to handle all screen resolution

Comment: I just updated my code. Setting the offset brings the Popup centre and that's what the user want.

Comment: OK for setting to the center using the offset, but maybe you should help him with the way of getting the total width?